# How to add noise to a PCM raw data

Tags: java, android, signal-processing

Now I have a loaded PCM raw byte array directly from a WAV file, now I have to add the noise to the original byte array. My requirement is that the result cannot be decoded without the knowledge of the added noise, I can also remove the noise if I know exactly what the noise is.
My current idea is convert the original byte array to short array, and generate a noise short array which has random generated number between 2^-15 and 2^15 and add these 2 arrays slot by slot. But looks like this method cannot guarantee that I can recover the original array.
Can someone give me some better idea how to do it?THank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a (Sound) signal, S(t).

You want to 'encrypt' this signal, creating E(t).

You can do this by adding Noise, N(t).

S(t) + N(t) = E(t).

And furthermore, E(t) - N(t) = S(t).

So now the problem is generating a unique 'noise'.

I would do this through a Pseudo-random number generator (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator), where you can pass the seeding information to the recipient.

Now, anybody who has the same seeds to create N(t) can compute E(t)-N(t)=S(t)

---

Response to comments:

@Bjorn:  It isn't encryption in a normal sense.  But, suppose you have some integer C mod [0 - 2^16-1].  Now, add some uniform random integer on the same range [0-2^16-1] to this.  The result is also a uniform random integer on this range.  Therefore, depending on the quality of your random sequence generator, you can create a non-decodeable signal (w/o having the original superimposed signal).  (I'll admit, this would not be the case without overflow).

@OP:  Your issue is decoding the number after it is passed along.

Suppose you have a binary string 10101010.  Now, you add 11110000 to this.
The result should look something like 01011010.  With an overflow into the 2^8'th place.

Now, 01011010 - 11110000 returns the same initial value: 10101010.  So this overflow actually serves as an assistance in masking the original signal

*this is provided you use a unique masking signal which you can generate again at the recipient.

Comment: A few things: 1. the sound won't really be encrypted (in any sense of the word). For one thing, you'll still be able to make out what the original sound was. 2. you'll need to think about the audio format. The OP suggests converting from bytes to shorts. This will work if the WAV file is 16-bit and shorts are 16-bit on your platform (they usually are).

Comment: @Bjorn The problem is: if I add a random value to a short value, the result maybe larger than the maximum value of short which is 2^15-1, if this happens, I may not get the original value back.

Answer (score 0):

Noise is by definition a (quasi)random disturbance in the signal. You cannot fully recover the original signal, only suppress it if you for example know the spectrum of the noise.